# Analyzing an experiment with nested variables in R -- Mice age, training runs, species, and treatment opportunities effect on 'memory'

Tags: r

so I have an experiment I'm trying to analyze where I have two different strains of mice, and I put them into a maze and they go to either a reward block (chocolate) or a control block as a "training run" then as a trial run I have two control blocks and see if they are able to 'remember' i.e. go back to where the chocolate block was in the maze.

I'm essentially trying to see what factors effect their ability the most, and I have data for mice species type (2 different species), number of training runs they got, age of the mice in weeks, and number of trial runs they got all in a data frame.

I believe I could somehow generate a glm model and keep reducing it to determine which has the highest effect.. but it's so much to reduce and determine which one has an effect that I'm sure there is a better more efficient way to go about it.. my data frame looks like this

```
> memory
    STRAIN AGE NUM_TRAIN COHORT RUN TREATMENT COUNT
1     CAST   1         1      1   1    reward    10
2     CAST   1         1      1   1   control    13
3     CAST   1         1      1   2    reward    12
4     CAST   1         1      1   2   control    14
5     CAST   1         1      1   3    reward    12
6     CAST   1         1      1   3   control    13
7     CAST   1         1      1   4    reward    10
8     CAST   1         1      1   4   control    10
9     CAST   1         1      1   5    reward    12
10    CAST   1         1      1   5   control    11
11    CAST   1         1      1   6    reward     9
12    CAST   1         1      1   6   control    11
13    CAST   1         1      1   7    reward    11
14    CAST   1         1      1   7   control     8
15    CAST   1         1      1   8    reward     9
```

Comment: is this part of your data frame? how many data points do you have in total (nrow(memory)). You don't have a lot of variables, so just do something like summary(glm(COUNT ~ TREATMENT + RUN,family="poisson",data=memory))

Comment: In my example, I only specify RUN and TREATMENT because all the other variables have the same value

Comment: I think you may want to fit one model, and calculate the standardized effect size for each variable of interest. Regardless, this seems more suited to stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @StupidWolf well this is only a sample of my data frame, there are 2 species, 4 different ages (weeks 1,5,10, or 15), etc. with over 5,500 rows of observations

Comment: Agree with @Axeman it might be more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. My suggestion would be to fit one model, summary(glm(COUNT ~ . ,family="poisson",data=memory)), and you can see the effects of each variable.